# Is it possible to "prelink" a dynamic library `.so` into an object file?

Tags: c, linker, ld

Imagine we had this project layout

```
./
 ├──libtardir/
 │   ├──include/
 │   │   └──...
 │   └──lib/
 │       └──libtar.so
 ├──check.c
 ├──main.c
 └──Makefile
```

In `check.c` we use the function `tar_open` which we get by including `#include <libtar.h>`, if we want to compile `check.c` down to an object file, we need only add `-I`, so `$(CC) -I./libtardir/include -c check.c`. Were we to pass `-ltar -L./libtar/lib` it would just be ignored, since those flags are only used (AFAIK) for linking. We can now do `$(CC) -ltar -L./libtardir/lib check.o main.c -o main` to get an executable (ignore the fact we could do this in one step).

My question then, is there an intermediate file I could make so the symbols are "prebaked" into the `.o` file? That is, some way I could make this makefile make sense:

```
check.o: check.c
    $(CC) -ltar -I./libtardir/include -L./libtardir/lib -c check.c

main: check.o
    $(CC) check.something main.c -o main
```

I am not asking about static libraries, I would still need to add `libtar` to the `rpath` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

As for why, I have a project with Nix, GHC, and C++, nix does some magic to `gcc` & `ld` which is not done to GHC, the build steps on my build system would be cleaner if something like this were possible.

Comment: Probably you could create a wrapper C file that includes all the necessary libtar function calls. This file would be compiled into an object file that you link with your other object files. It wouldn't eliminate the need for the library in the linking stage, but it can encapsulate the usage of libtar?

Comment: You can compile `check` to a shared library `check.so`, and link it with `libtar.so`. Then when you link with `check.so`, `libtar.so` is automatically pulled in. You cannot do that with .o or .a files, only .so.

Comment: Alternatively, you *probably* can generate a linker script together with the .o file, and have that script contain all information about the .o file and all shared libraries needed by that .o file. You then pass the script, rather than the .o file, to the linker. But I have no experience with this.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI What do you mean by linking `check.so` to `libtar.so`? I tried this but I am guessing you mean something else?

`$(CC) --shared -ltar -I./libtardir/include -L./libtardir/lib check.c -o libcheck.so`

`$(CC) -lcheck -L. main.c -o main`

Comment: no I mean exactly this, what doesn't work?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The first command runs fine, but the second one I get:
`ld: warning: libtar.so.0, needed by ./libcheck.so, not found` & `ld: ./libcheck.so: undefined reference to `tar_open'`, It works if I include again the previous flags.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention an important thing, For the second command to work, you need `libtar.so` to be already installed in a default place like `/usr/lib` where `ld` can find it. Or you need to add something like `-Wl,-rpath-link=libtardir/lib` to the second command.

Comment: I think you should ask a Nix-specific question if you have a problem with Nix.

Comment: I don't have a nix specific question, I (simplifying) essentially have a makefile in which I compile C code with the nix provided C compiler, it already has the flags I want baked in... But after that, I need to take that object file and combine it with GHC, but GHC doesn't have the same wrapper, this is no issue, you simply pass the environment variable that has all the flags to GHC, and it works again. My thought was just: "It would be nice if after I made the object file, that information was just encoded inside it".